# Remove some HTML comments in a set of files using sed/awk

Tags: html, regex, awk, sed, html-parsing

The specific set of files in my case, are all included in a specified directory and its sub-directories.
I need to make sure it does not delete conditional rules for IE browsers, like `<!--[if IE 9]>`.
Here is a sample dataset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Should not delete the conditional below -->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html>
<![endif]-->
<head></head>
<body>
<p>Some content</p>
<!--Single line without space-->
<!-- Single line with spaces -->
<!-- Multi
     Line
     Comment -->

<div>Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But conditional rules are HTML comments, so you're really trying to delete *some* HTML comments.

Comment: maybe `<!--[^\[].*?-->`

Comment: if `.` doesn't stand for newlines then you can replace it by `(.|\s)`

Comment: Can we play a fun game of *"you post a regex which you think will parse HTML comments except conditionals, and we post ways it won't"*? @maraca's approach, I counter with `<a onclick='javascript:alert("<!-- test -->")'>hello</a>` - it's not a comment but will be removed as if it was. @Steven Penny's might get confused with `foo <!-- x <!-- --> bar -->` This possibly isn't valid HTML, but Chrome makes `bar` visible. Also, removing comments might remove live JavaScript ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp - Tips and Notes section). Use a HTML parser.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler obviously it doesn't work for stuff like that, I know Zalgo the pony or whatever, but sometimes you can do it supervised with an unsave regex (e.g. using an advanced text editor) instead of bothering with parsing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

This will not handle more complex cases, but could get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/<!--/ {comm = 1}
comm == 0
/-->/ {comm = 0}
```